# Cannot compile C# project with gRPC

Tags: c#, grpc

I'm trying to create a C# gRPC client for a server I have. I have the `.proto` file, the file's build action is set to `ProtoBuf`, I have created a C# class for wrapping around the client. Everything looks fine in the IDE, no red squiggly lines, everything is good.

My protobuf file's package name is `controlpanel`, and the IDE has no issues with the types being imported via `using Controlpanel;`, no issues with that, or the types that come from it in the IDE.

The `.proto` file is valid, as I have used it to create both a server and a client in Go.

However, the issue comes when I try to build it.

I get errors like

```
error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Controlpanel' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

I've checked the `obj/` directory, and it appears the code is generated just fine.

I have no idea what the issue is, and I have searched the Internet for about an hour, finding nothing about the issue I'm having. To the point where my only 3 search results are in Chinese.

Answer (score 4):

I ran into the same problem when using gRPC in a WPF application. There is an issue on Github: https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/18624

Workaround:

Move code generation with proto files to a regular class library. You can then reference the class library from the WPF app and use the generated types inside it.